# TYPO3 fluid: Get all content IDs from page

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

is there an possibility to get all the content IDs from a page?
I tried something like this:

```
    <v:resource.record
      table="tt_content"
      uid="1811"
      field="pid"
      as="item"
    >
        <f:debug>{item}</f:debug>

    </v:resource.record>
```

But it only gives me the parent ID and i cant swap the attributes to make it work.
Thanks

Comment: what do you expect? your query is like: `SELECT pid as 'item' FROM tt_content WHERE uid = 1811`. How should that result in a list of `uid`s? BTW: what do you really want to do? I doubt you want to output that id list.

Comment: Maybe, a dataprocessor could help to solve your requirement: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html?highlight=dataprocess#databasequeryprocessor

Comment: Hi, no i made a misstake. I need the opposite. Select pid from tt_content where pid = 312. Result should be 1811.And yes, it only a part of the the problem. I need  to get the input of an flux flux field from another page. I found a solution with <flux:form.data> but for this i need the uid of the element. So i need to get to get. Sorry for the answer, i wrote it with my smartphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get Page ID of content element with UID 312:

```
<v:resource.record
      table="tt_content"
      uid="312"
      field="pid"
      as="item"
    ><f:debug title="query 1: page of CE">{item}</f:debug></v:resource.record>
```

get UID of content elements in page with UID 123:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.UidList" data="{pid:123}" />
```

typoscript:

```
lib.UidList = CONTENT
lib.UidList {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList.field = pid
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = uid
    renderObj.wrap = |, |*| |, |*| |
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but pid isn't a valid argument:

Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Resource\RecordViewHelper: pid. Valid arguments are: table, field, record, uid, as

Comment: bad realisation of ext:vhs. I changed to a solution in typoscript. Be aware that you only get a comma separated list, you can't get an array from typoscript. If you want to use those `uid`s you might need to modify the renderObj

Comment: Thank you, i'll check ot out after xmas. Actually every page onyl have one content element, so a list should be fine. :)

Comment: Your solution returns just returns commatas for every content element per pid.

Comment: It works if you change renderObj.date to renderObj.field. If you change your Answer i can aprove it. Thank you! :)

Comment: fixed the `renderObj`